# How to insert print statement in every method of class in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I would like to add a print statement at the start of every method in a C# class to help out with debugging. Basically, I want to turn this

```
public class SomeClass {
  public void Foo() {
    ...
  }

  public void Bar() {
    ...
  }
}
```

into this

```
public class SomeClass {
  public void Foo() {
    Console.WriteLine("SomeClass.Foo started");
    ...
  }

  public void Bar() {
    Console.WriteLine("SomeClass.Bar started");
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. Are there any plugins or built-in VS features that would allow me to do this?

Comment: What will these print statements help you do? You say "to help out with debugging" but "`printf` style" debugging is usually an option of last resort. What *problem* do you think that these solve?

Comment: I mean, you can look at the Call Stack to see the sequence of things. I don't see how this is practical. You could probably edit the template for classes in VS to always include an empty constructor with a call to Console.WriteLine.... but that isn't worth anybody's time.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have a Heisenbug that doesn't happen when the debugger is attached and very rarely and randomly happens otherwise. What I want it basically a trace of the execution path when the bug happens.

Comment: @insane_developer I thought Call Stack will only show the stack when a breakpoint is hit. I'm not attaching a debugger since that is not an option for this particular bug. Is there a way to make Call Stack show a list of all the methods that were executed?

Comment: @MirzaDobric I see, you're dealing with an intermittent issue. In that case, it's better to use a logger to capture this info. How many classes are involved? Too many to do it manually? By the way, you never mentioned that you cannot use the debugger for this. That's key info.

Comment: @insane_developer I'm not sure for how many classes I'll need to do this for but it'll be at least a handful. Also, I don't need this log statement just in the constructor but in every existing method. I can write something to do this but I figured I'd ask first if the community knows of an existing solution. I didn't think mentioning that I can't use the debugger is necessary. In my mind, the question is pretty clear and I didn't think I would need to provide a reason for why I'm asking, you know?

Comment: I believe people are asking about the deeper reasoning because of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You asked about X (adding print statements), but what you really need help with is Y (debugging an intermittent problem).  In general, the "reason why you're asking" can often be as valuable or more valuable in shaping the answer.  For example: if the root cause is a race condition, perhaps adding a bunch of log statements reduces the chances of the race condition occurring.  A different approach could work better.

Comment: As others pointed out the why is often very important and as @Insane_developer mentioned logging could be helpful for this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing  As Sean Kelly mentioned logging can at times obscure the issues you're looking for as well, but it's the place to start.

Comment: @MikeJ Is there a different way of doing logging that will log every method in a class when it executes? I thought what I showed in the example classes is logging but maybe there is some other kind of logging that I'm not aware of. Maybe some setting in VS that I can turn on and it will add a logging statement to the beginning of every method?

Comment: @SeanSkelly I get what you mean about the XY problem. However, there is an assumption there that I am asking for the wrong thing. In this case, I wasn't. I am aware of different approaches to debugging which I have tried and which didn't work. I kept the question very focused because I didn't want to provide distractions by going on at length about what all I tried and why other methods of diagnosing didn't work. Sometimes a question really is just a question ;)

Answer (score 0):

@MirzaDobric, I'll move to an answer just to give a little more room.  Are there any other built in ways to log every method call...  I can only think of one that sort of fits the bill and that's aspect oriented programming.  I say "sort of" because this is even more intrusive than the old style printf debugging you're after because of the bigger impact on the runtime behavior.

But you can read more about a couple ways to do it here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/february/aspect-oriented-programming-aspect-oriented-programming-with-the-realproxy-class

If you can't use a debugger, and you can't use a profiler, then your probably better off manually adding tracing in the handful of places you need it.  That link I sent you in the comment should suffice for explanations of that.  Note that I say tracing but it would be the same as using something like log4net or serilog. The important benifits of all three would be to add external configuration to control when and how much it logs so you can turn off the logging and turn it back on without having to recompile and redeploy the application.

Again there's always the risk this is going to be wasted effort because if the problem is that sporadic it's possible the logging will alter the runtime behavior enough to either prevent it from happening or cause it to happen in some place the logging doesn't cover.  But if you've got no other choice then start logging and hope for the best.